# Forward and Reverse Bias regions for voltage versus current of diode

Tags: diodes, bias

Below I have the graph of the voltage of a diode versus its current. As you can see, the forward bias region is when Vd>0 and reverse bias when Vd<0. My question is: In which region does Vd=0 fall in?
[image]

Comment: Would deciding this question change anything at all about the actual behavior of the diode?

Comment: I just need to know whether Vd=0 is forward or reverse bias.

Comment: Why? How will it change any circuit you design?

Comment: I guess it does not. Another question for you, why is there a slight drop in Vd when Id increases?

Comment: who says it does? If you use the passive current convention, then \$\frac{dV}{dI}\$ is always positive for an ideal diode.

Comment: There are some esoteric diodes types (Esaki, Gunn) that have negative differential resistance at some point in their I-V curve, but it doesn't happen at \$V_D=0\$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Null is neither a positive nor negative number (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative), **Vd=0 is neither forward nor reverse bias**.